# Feeding R agnes object into cutree

Tags: r, clustering

I'm using `agnes` to group terms that frequently appear with one another in a set of documents. I get a dendrogram which verifies that things are working as expected. From this, I'd like to to retrieve the cluster of each member. I'm using cutree to cut the tree at a specified height, but it is returning one extra cluster, I'm not sure why.

```
length(flex75$order.lab)
[1] 132
length(cutree(flex75, h = 1.5))
[1] 133
```

It occurs for varying heights, even up to `h = max(flex75$height)` and all clusters = 1. So I cannot bind the labels to their clusters.

EDIT:

I found the issue to be when I reorder `flex75$height` to be in ascending order (I was previously receiving an error that: the 'height' component of 'tree' is not sorted (increasingly)). I was also reordering the `$order` and `$order.lab` components using the `$height` order, and turns out that `height` is of length n-1 and `order`/`order.lab` is of length n.

My question now is: What is the relationship between the agnes object's `$height` vector, and the `$order`/`$order.lab` vectors? Can I permute the heights, as I have, and feed that object into cutree? Should any of the object's other properties be correspondingly changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457473/strange-error-of-hierarchical-clustering-in-r). Another user was getting a similar error about ordering `height`, but theirs came with the suggestion to apply `as.hclust()` first. I converted the `agnes` object to an `hclust` and passed that directly into `cutree`. That seemed to solve the problem.